# Not getting even thickness with solidfy

Tags: modifiers

Not getting perfect even thickness with solidfy modifier. I have simple box and i want to give 3mm box thickness to it. I tried complex and all other options inside it. Non of its working. Face are all facing correct. Scale rotation are also 0 and 1. Any suggestion why not getting thickness.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The solidify modifier won't give your perfect geometry here because you have geometry sticking at 90° (as per the answer) and also you have poles where three faces join orthogonally et one point, so the interpolation between the normals is messed up.

Comment: @Gorgious. This is the default cube. In model scale and created a rectangular shape. When i extrude the top edge i got this result https://imgur.com/a/KKQkNsa

Comment: So you can see why what you are trying to do is impossible : you are messing up the normal interpolation used by the solidify modifier when you create the box flaps. Think of it as the modifier needs to know what is inside and what is outside. Until you add the flaps it is pretty obvious, but with the flaps, the inside and outside are not as clear to the algorithm, especially at the very point where the edges merge creating a pole

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the bit that sticks out you have another face extending out at a 90 degree angle. The Solidify modifier is intersecting itself right there and making things go strange.

If you remove that overhang, switch the modifier to Simple, and enable Even Thickness you will get a better result.

Comment: This is the default cube. In model scale and created a rectangular shape. When i extrude the top edge i got this result https://imgur.com/a/KKQkNsa

Comment: @gorgious explained why you are getting the ghost edge pretty well. If you flip the direction of the modifier to -0.03m it might make more sense visually what's happening. You can see the modifier is following the direction of the normals and the artifact you see is the point where the direction changes. The algorithm has split the difference and is forced into a 45 degree angle.

Answer (score -2):

See this picture:

[image]

This is complex mode in solidify modifiers,

There is and option below **Complex** which (**Thickness Mode**) set this to **Even** not on constraint.

**Even thickness**: This is similar to Simple Mode with Even Thickness and High Quality Normals. It adjusts for sharp corners, but may not always work when more than three faces come together.

Maybe it will help you>>>>

Comment: Did not work got this wired result https://imgur.com/a/ecocaDi